# How to access state inside of event function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that is [using a calendar](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar) to handle some date picking stuff.  My jsx is pretty simple you can see it below:

```
  state = { 
    date: new Date(),
  };

  render() {
    return (
    //left out for the sake of brevity...
    Date: {this.state.date.toString()}
    <Calendar onChange={dateChange} activeStartDate={this.state.date} />
    //...
  )}

  function dateChange(date) {
    console.log(date)
    console.log(this)
  }
```

This renders my calendar fine and the date string after `Date:` looks correct.  My problem is that `this` is always null when I change the date.  I would like to be able to access `this.state.date` from the `dateChange` function but I can't figure out how to do this.  I attempted to bind using the code below:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dateChange = this.dateChange.bind(this)
  }
```

But this returns the error `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`.

How do I make this and by extension my current state available in my `dateChange` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it inside of your class, as a class method, without function word

```
class yourClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { date: new Date() };
        this.dateChange = this.dateChange.bind(this);
      }

    render() {
        return (
        //left out for the sake of brevity...
        <Calendar onChange={this.dateChange} activeStartDate={this.state.date} />
        //...
        );
    }

    dateChange(date) {
        console.log(date);
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

That way you can use `this.dateChange = this.dateChange.bind(this)` to bind `this` to your class

I also moved the state to your constructor; that's where it is normally initialized

And I removed `Date: {this.state.date.toString()}` because I am not sure what were you trying to do wit it (is it another Component?) - anyway I do not think it affects the response to your question

Comment: When I try this i get the error: `Unexpected token, expected ";"` at the new `dateChange` function declaration

Comment: I added some missing semicolons ; there should be one at the end of each statement.

Comment: Hrrm, now it's throwing `dateChange is not defined` from my `onChange={dateChange}` code. (also, I didn't downvote - this is helping)

Comment: Ahh - just had to change it to `this.dateChange` and it worked - thanks!

Comment: yes sorry, on the copy paste I missed to update it. Answer updated - I am glad it helped!